# Text disappears in ie

Tags: css-float

I have tried adding z-index, experimenting with different div names but I have had no luck.

I tried inspecting the element but it is almost as if the sidebar is going above the entire website and outside the parent div...

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: add positioning: `top:0; left:0` and `position:fixed`. That'll fix it

Comment: @giorgio unfortunately that does not fix the issue. I think it has something to do with the attempt to rotate my text messing with the entire div. If I don't have an answer in the next couple hours, I may just use two separate divs and see if that makes a difference

Comment: I added these in dev tools on your site, and that worked for me :)

Comment: I played around with it a little and used two divs with position absolute and it worked. I used positioning as you recommended and it worked! I didn't see the results at first because of caching. Thank you so much. I am new here and I was wondering if I can close or mark this as complete? or give you credit for the right answer / rep points of some sort? @giorgio

Answer (score 1):

A couple of pointers

I added to `.sidebar`

```
  top:100%;
  left:0;
```

and I took out

```
translate(1em,0) /*This was causing bar to shift instead of bracing to window*/
```

here is a working snippet

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height:100vh;
  height:100vw;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.main {
  background-color: blue;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
}

.rest {
  background-color: blue;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
}

.sidebar {
  z-index: 1000;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  transform:rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  top:100%;
  left:0;
 padding:0px;
  width:100vh;
 margin:none;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  -ms-transform: none;
  -ms-transform-origin: none;
  -ms-writing-mode: tb-rl;
  *writing-mode: tb-rl;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  background-color: white;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="main">
<div class="sidebar">
testestestste 
</div>
</div>

<div class="rest" style="background-color: yellow;">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```